# PHP: Check if array key is specific string

Tags: php, arrays, string, if-statement, explode

I'm trying to create an if statement. based on the string of the

```
$var = "Apple : Banana";
$array = explode(":", $var);
print_r($array); //array([0] => 'Apple' [1] => 'Banana')

if ($array[1] == "Banana") {
  echo "Banana!";
}
```

Comment: Please trim the values and then check against "Banana"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string has space before and after `:`, so array will be

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(6) "Apple " 
    [1]=> string(7) " Banana" 
}
```

You need to remove space from items using [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) and then compare it.

```
$var = "Apple : Banana";
$array = explode(":", $var);

if (trim($array[1]) == "Banana") {
    echo "Banana!";
}
```

Comment: Or `$array = explode(" : ", $var);`

Comment: Yes @RiggsFolly You should post that as an answer. Way simpler

Comment: No actually I think your method s more reliable. In case they get `$var = "Apple : Banana:Orange";` as a string

Comment: Well, now I just feel dumb :) Thank you so much tho! 
I also recommend anyone doing this to store each trimmed value in new variable:
`$value_a = trim($array[0]);
$value_b = trim($array[1]);`

Answer (score 4):

Your condition doesn't work because each element of array has space. You should remove excess spaces. You can use [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function to remove spaces and [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function to apply `trim` in each element of the array.
For example:

```
$var = "Apple : Banana";
$array = array_map('trim', explode(":", $var));
if ($array[1] == "Banana") {
  echo "Banana!";
}
```

result:

> Banana!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using preg_split and regex

```
$parts = preg_split('/\s+\:\s+/', $var);
```

Then on $parts you will get:

> array(2) {   [0]=>   string(5) "Apple"   [1]=>   string(6) "Banana" }

Comment: Sure, but trim version below feels simpler